# What resharper 5 patterns do you use?

Tags: c#, idioms, resharper-5.0

As resharper 5 now has DIY patterns, what patterns have you writen that fix coding idioms that you've seen? Is there an online resharper pattern repository? I thought here would be a logical place to vote for your favorite patterns.

I think of this as [programming in the small](http://ivan.truemesh.com/archives/cat_programming_in_the_small.html).

Comment: A Resharper pattern repository would rock!

Comment: Surprised there are not more answers here. Would love to see how others take advantage of this feature.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently doing a deep refactoring in a legacy application. Here are some ReSharper (6.1) patterns I'm using to fix some code issues:

### Apply the 'using' pattern

Search pattern:

```
$type$ $var$ = $expr$;
$stmt$
$var$.Dispose();
$var$ = null;
```

Replace pattern:

```
using (var $var$ = $expr$)
{
    $stmt$
}
```

### Apply the 'using' pattern (with return inside)

Search pattern:

```
$type$ $var$ = $expr$;
$stmt$
$var$.Dispose();
$var$ = null;
return $something$;
```

Replace pattern:

```
using (var $var$ = $expr$)
{
    $stmt$
    return $something$;
}
```

*Resharper does not recognize the following opportunity of using the `??` operator, so I've created a pattern for it. Of course, it makes a conditional assignment become a simple assignment (to the same value when the `$nullable$` is not null); still, I find the resulting code to be easier on the eye.*

### Use the '??' operator

Search pattern:

```
if (!$nullable$.HasValue) $nullable$ = $value$;
```

Replace pattern:

```
$nullable$ = $nullable$ ?? $value$;
```

And, finally, one of my favorites:

### C# is not Java - you may use "==" for comparing strings

Search pattern:

```
$str1$.Equals($str2$)
```

Replace pattern:

```
$str1$ == $str2
```

Answer (score 4):

No full-fledged online SSR pattern catalog exists though we wish there was one. This is definitely in a to-do list for the future.
However, on the [ReSharper documentation page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html), there's a link to a [sample Pattern Catalog](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/PublicPatternCatalog.zip) based on patterns used in ReSharper team.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `IDictionary<TKey,TItem>.TryGetValue` instead of looking up by key twice**

- `$dict$` is an `IDictionary<,>`
- `$key$` is exactly one argument
- `$moreCode$` is any number of statements
- `$valType$` is a type
- `$varName$` is an identifier

Search pattern:

```
if ($dict$.ContainsKey($key$)) {
    $valType$ $varName$ = $dict$[$key$];
    $moreCode$
}
```

Replace pattern:

```
$valType$ $varName$;
if ($dict$.TryGetValue($key$, out $varName$)) {
    $moreCode$
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found out this even existed this morning. First thing I did was try to make sure null or constants were always on the left side of an equality check, to prevent unintentionally setting an object to null.

I haven't figured out constants yet, but null checking was:

```
Search pattern: if($expr$ == null) $stmt$
Replace Pattern: if(null == $expr$) $stmt$
Placeholders: 
    expr: expression of type System.Object (or derived type)
    stmt: minimum of one statement, no maximum
```

Then I copied that pattern and made a simple Find-only pattern:

```
Search pattern: if($expr$ = null) $stmt$
Placeholders: 
    expr: expression of type System.Object (or derived type)
    stmt: minimum of one statement, no maximum
```

This one will actually find any instances where you did set something to null in an if statement, whether you meant to or not.

I'm seriously about to lose a few days writing patterns. My software will be better for it, though.

**EDIT**: Here's another one that irritates me in my code base. Since Directory.CreateDirectory checks for the existence of the directory internally, there's no sense in making a redundant call to Directory.Exists beforehand.

```
Search pattern:

if (!Directory.Exists($path$))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory($path$);
}

Replace Pattern:

Directory.CreateDirectory($path$);

Placeholders: 
    path: identifier
```